# How to shift focus back to parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following is the image of the parent screen:

[image]

On click of popup a popup window appears:

[image]

[image]

On click of **create** the alert message appears on the child window.

I tried window.close still the alert message appears on child window then the window gets closed.

Is there any way to make the alert appears on the parent window?

Parent HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>ParentWindow</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
    window.open(theURL,winName,features).focus();
  }
  </script>
  <form name="frmMain" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtSel" id="txtSel">
    <input name="btnSelect" type="button" id="btnSelect" value="popup" 
           onClick="javascript:MM_openBrWindow('DrawBinPage.html','pop', 'scrollbars=no,width=350,height=210')">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Child HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bin Details Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
                </script>             
  <br> <br>
  &ensp;&ensp;Length&ensp;<input type="text" id="GoodsLength" >
  <br> <br>
  &ensp;&ensp;Width &ensp;<input type="text" id="GoodsWidth" >
  <br><br>
  &ensp;&ensp;Height&ensp;<input type="text" id="Goodsheight">

  <br><br>

  <input name="btnSelect" type="button" id="btnSelect" value="Create" style="width:80px;height:30px" onClick="Createnew()"/> &ensp;&ensp; 
  <input name="btnSelect" type="button" id="btnSelect" value="Close Window" style="width:150px;height:30px" onclick="window.close()" />

</body>
<script>
function Createnew(){
  alert('hi');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.opener.alert('hi');`

Comment: @SamuelLiew window.opener.alert('hi'); still shows the alert mesage in the child window

Comment: Then you need to update your question with the `MM_openBrWindow` function, because without knowing how that function opens a new window, we cannot answer this question.

Comment: @SamuelLiew the function is mentioned at the beginning of the parent html   
    function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { 
        window.open(theURL,winName,features).focus();
        }

Comment: what about window.postMessage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage